# Convert web server from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have been using this script, found online not my work!

In python2 it works perfectly, but in python3 (using 2 to 3) we get the error:

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I can't figure out how to encode `sys.argv[2]`, if I replace it with static credentials: `b'user:pass'` the error goes away. This is not a problem actually, I would prefer it, but it creates another problem: setting the port. How/where is `sys.argv[1]` (the port number) actually used? Any help much appreciated.

```
import os
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import sys
import base64

os.chdir("H:\\")

key = ""

class AuthHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    ''' Main class to present webpages and authentication. '''
    def do_HEAD(self):
        print "send header"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_AUTHHEAD(self):
        print "send header"
        self.send_response(401)
        self.send_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=\"Marradio\"')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        global key
        ''' Present frontpage with user authentication. '''
        if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write('no auth header received')
            pass
        elif self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == 'Basic '+key:
            SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
            pass
        else:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write(self.headers.getheader('Authorization'))
            self.wfile.write('not authenticated')
            pass

def test(HandlerClass = AuthHandler,
         ServerClass = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    BaseHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass, ServerClass)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv)<3:
        print "usage SimpleAuthServer.py [port] [username:password]"
        sys.exit()
    key = base64.b64encode(sys.argv[2])

    test()
```

Comment: did you tried `sys.argv[2].encode()` ?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\server.py", line 52, in <module>
    key = base64.b64encode(sys.argv[2])
  File "C:\Python36\lib\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the string with a byte value:

```
base64string = base64.b64encode( bytes(s, "utf-8") )
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, that fixed that error, but now we have another!

  `File "E:\Python\FTP_server\py3-Marradio_server.py", line 30, in do_GET
    if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
AttributeError: 'HTTPMessage' object has no attribute 'getheader'`

Comment: It is also defaulting to port 8000, mind you I still don't understand how the port was set, sys.argv[1] is not referenced anywhere yet it works under python2.

Comment: OK so, getheaders should be get in python 3, I would expect 2to3 to spot that.